# changes to .env file not recognized

Tags: node.js, environment-variables

My .env file contains the following line:

DBENV='REMOTE'

when I was using a local database before I had it set to

DBENV='LOCAL'

But when I try to run my file, it does not recognize the change. It thinks it's still set to 'LOCAL':

[image: screenshot of app debug session]

In fact, when I delete the .env file altogether it still says that. I assume that means it's looking at some other .env file, but I don't know where.

The .env file is located in the root of my project's directory:

[image: project directory]

How do I get process.env to look at the correct environment file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the assignment operator (single `=`) in your `if` expression. This operator returns the value it assigned and is therefore equivalent to

```
process.env.DBENV = 'LOCAL'
if ('LOCAL') {
   //... 
}
```

which always evaluates to `true`.

Use comparison (`==` or `===`) instead.

Comment: OMG what a space cadet! I can't believe I didn't see that. Thank you.

Comment: No problem. We all had these kinds of issues at some point. :D

Answer (score 1):

Are you remembering to `require` your `.env` file properly?

[`require('dotenv').config()`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv)

Also, are you remembering to restart your server after each change?